# Using a reset button to return to the login page in php

Tags: php

This is the code that I currently have. This is redirecting to a page that tells the user that the login information is incorrect. Upn submission of the UN/PW would it be better for it to stay on the login page with error script, and if so how would I do that?

```
<?php
session_start();
    include 'dbConnection.php';

    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userdb WHERE uid='$uid' and pwd='$pwd'";  
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Your username or password is incorrect!";
        echo "Please try again!"."<br><br>";
        echo "<button type='reset'>RESET";
            if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {
            header("Location: login.php");
        echo "</button>";   }
    }else {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    }
```

Comment: probably because; you're outputting before header. and/or `if (isset($_POST['reset'])) {...}` is never satisfied.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: what does http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php throw back?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php - Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Comment: I'm new to this. Not even sure what that is or how to use it

Comment: `<?php  ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` then the rest of your code; what does it show? headers sent?

Comment: so, in the echo's the reset button needs to come before the other echo's?

Comment: no, it's either echo "or" header; can't use both. You can redirect with JS or meta tag though just not with the header.

Comment: ok, would the button need to be in the source code to redirect after echoing that the information is incorrect?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: Why is it that when I'm not understanding what someone is saying and trying to get confirmation everyone starts on sql injection? it's on a test server and I'm not worried about that yet. I'm still trying to learn FUNCTIONAL coding in PHP.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here Don? It's hard to follow. You're going to have to edit your question to explain exactly what you want to do here. That button reset... in its place; I just don't know what the question's about. Reset buttons belong in a form with a POST method.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: I understand that, I am simply trying to get the code to do what I want it to do. If I knew all about how PHP worked and how to secury

Comment: secure it from day one I would code it accordingly. I don't and have not gotten past just trying to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bump in the right direction. $db below replaces your `$conn` included from `dbConnect.php` and
returns an instance of the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) class.

```
<?php

session_start();

$db = new mysqli('db_host', 'db_user', 'db_password', 'db_name');

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM userdb WHERE uid = ? and pwd = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['uid'], $_POST['pwd']);

$stmt->execute();

if ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    header('Location: login.php?error=1');
    exit;
}

$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

header('Location: account.php');
```

This assumes you ahve 3 pages:

- `login.php` - displays your form and errors. Use the `error=1` querystring on `login.php` to conditionally display an invalid credentials error.
- `doLogin.php` - the `login.php` page posts here. This handles the login attempt.
- `account.php` - the page you redirect to with a successful login.

Let `doLogin.php` be responsible for one thing; performing the login.

Let `login.php`be responseible for one thing; presenting the user with the state of their login attempt.

Comment: I get error Fatal error: Call to undefined function fetch_assoc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hussars\userLogin.php on line 13 with this code

Comment: Should be `$stmt->fetch_assoc()`